# Grow View perforn Action and Shrink View

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I use [JHChainableAnimations](https://github.com/jhurray/JHChainableAnimations) to grow (scale) a view set a new value and then shrink (scale) the view to its original size again.

I tried to do:

```
    var isGrowing = true
    self.badgeView?.transformScale()(2).animate()(3)
      self.badgeView?.animationCompletion = {
        if isGrowing {
          isGrowing = false
          self.badgeView?.badgeText = "\(self.selectionCounter)"
          self.badgeView?.transformScale()(1).animate()(3)
        }
    }
```

But it does not work that way. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example in [JHChainableAnimations](https://github.com/jhurray/JHChainableAnimations) you have to set animationCompletion before starting an animation and animationCompletion type must be JHAnimationCompletion

```
var isGrowing = true
self.badgeView?.animationCompletion = JHAnimationCompletion(){
    if isGrowing {
      isGrowing = false
      self.badgeView?.badgeText = "\(self.selectionCounter)"
      self.badgeView?.transformScale()(0.5).animate()(3)
    }
}
self.badgeView?.transformScale()(2).animate()(3)
```

Comment: The view gets bigger but not smaller to its original size again.

Comment: @confile Check the edited answer. The problem was transformScale factor, it should be set to 0.5 and thats because when you grow a view of lets say 10 point by 2 it becomes 10*2=20. When you shrink it 1 factor its stay 20 because 20*1 = 20. So it should be 20*0.5 = 10